# Why does CopyRect WinAPI function exist?

Tags: winapi

There is the [CopyRect WinAPI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-copyrect), which simply copies a `RECT` to another.

I've been interested in the reason for the existence of the function ever since I dug it up.
Is the assignment operator (`=`) or `CopyMemory` function not suitable for copying `RECT`s? Should I use the `CopyRect` function whenever possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Raymond Chen answered my question!](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200224-00/?p=103472)

Copying a `RECT` generated a bunch of code. `CopyRect` saved memory in the era which we had only 256KB of memory.

Nowadays, we don't have to use it because manually copying a `RECT` can be done with a few instructions.

Answer (score 4):

`CopyRect` is an old function, which is present in Win32 API mostly for the compartibility sake, like `WinExec`, `GetVersion` and so on. Its source code is pretty simple: 
[image]

On start it checks both parameters for the `NULL` values and then copies 4 members of the source record to the destination through the intermediate register. Perhaps there is a point in using this function, if you are operating with the `RECT` pointers. Otherwise - direct assigment is much cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

The `CopyRect` function is (probably) designed for use with languages that don't allow direct assignments to structures! In `C++` you can have, say: `RECT src{ 0, 0, 10, 10 }, dst;` then (somewhere, anywhere): `dst = src;`. However, there are some languages that don't allow this, so you have the function to do it. (It's a very long time since I wrote anything in `Pascal`, but how would you do it there? Or in `COBOL`??)

Similar arguments can be made for functions like `SetRect()` and `EqualRect()`, of course. But, the answer to your question depends, primarily, on what language you are using (none specified in tags) and, that language permitting, on your personal coding preference. (But note, if efficiency is a concern, calling a `WinAPI` function will ***always*** involve an actual call, not an inline!)

Comment: No problem assigning records in pascal